# SPARQL bordering countries example

Tags: sparql

Can anyone show me any SPARQL query to get all bordering contries of all countries from http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/factbook/sparql?

For example Afghanistan has:
factbook:landboundary   db:China,
factbook:landboundary   db:Iran,
factbook:landboundary   db:Pakistan,
factbook:landboundary   db:Tajikistan,
factbook:landboundary   db:Turkmenistan

My try of getting data:

```
SELECT ?country ?name ?neighbour
WHERE {
?country rdf:type factbook:Country .
?country rdfs:label ?name.
OPTIONAL{
  ?country factbook:landboundary ?neighbour.
 }
}
```

ended with following message:

```
rethrew: de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.D2RQException: Table 'factbook.neighbors' doesn't exist: SELECT DISTINCT `T0_neighbors`.`name_encoded` FROM `bordercountries` AS `T0_bordercountries`, `neighbors` AS `T0_neighbors`, `countries` AS `T0_countries` WHERE `T0_bordercountries`.`Landboundaries_bordercountries_title` = `T0_neighbors`.`Name` AND `T0_bordercountries`.`Name` = `T0_countries`.`Name` AND `T0_countries`.`name_encoded` = 'Aruba' (E0)
```

I've asked the same question on http://answers.semanticweb.com but no luck yet so I'm trying my luck here

Comment: Impatient much? This question was posted _twice_ on answers.semanticweb.com. Anyway. Answered here: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/18608/how-do-i-get-bordering-countries-from-cia-factbook-d2r-endpoint

Answer (score 1):

The failure seems to be caused by an internal system error. Your SPARQL query does not have any syntax errors and the predicates you provided are valid according to the data.

However, I don't understand how your query is supposed to return the neighbors of one specific country. Maybe you want to try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?neighbor
WHERE {
    ?neighbor rdf:type factbook:Country .
    ?neighbor factbook:landboundary db:Afghanistan .
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't set the question right. I've fixed it now. I want all neighbors of all countries. Your query doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Very much later and not exactly an answer to this question (the SPARQL Endpoint to the CIA Factbook seem to be down at the moment), but WikiData has a few examples how to get bordering countries according to their data set at https://query.wikidata.org/

E.g. if you open the examples and search for "border", you get a query for "countries sharing a border with Cameroon":

```
#Population of countries sharing a border with Cameroon
#defaultView:LineChart
SELECT ?country ?year ?population ?countryLabel WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?country ?year (AVG(?population) AS ?population) WHERE {
      {
        SELECT ?country (str(YEAR(?date)) AS ?year) ?population WHERE {
          ?country wdt:P47 wd:Q1009;  # shares border with Cameroon
                   p:P1082 ?populationStatement.
          ?populationStatement ps:P1082 ?population;
                               pq:P585 ?date.
        }
      }
    }
    GROUP BY ?country ?year
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

To understand this one has to know (or figure out) that `wd:Q1009` is actually Cameroon. Not sure how to do this.
 This example also displays a - imo not very useful - display of the population of the surrounding countries by year.

A simpler version without the extra data is:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P47 wd:Q1009  # shares border with Cameroon
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}
```

(The `SERVICE wikibase:label` is a [WikiData extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service))

Finally all bordering neighbours for all countries might be:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?neighbourLabel ?neighbour WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256;
           wdt:P47 ?neighbour
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
} ORDER BY ?countryLabel ?neighbourLabel
```